# D3.js- Binding an object's name with its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using D3js and I have a data that looks like this:

```
var data1=[{name:'fruits', value:2},{name:'veggies', value:3},{name:'milk', value:5},{name:'empty', value:0}];
```

eg: fruits- red color square
    veggies- green color square
    milk - white color square

I've created something like a square with different colors for each name in the data so that I can apply different transition paths to it. I want to generate the number of squares for each name in the data based on their values. For example, if I call the data with the name "milk", I want 5 white squares (value of milk is 5) to be generated instead of just one square with the value 5.

Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/25QHv/2/

I tried a couple of ways to do that, but nothing actually worked. Please help me....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: A loop from 1 to the value? Not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: When I call an object's name, for eg: fruit, I want 2( its corresponding value) squares to be generated. var da=["fruits","veggies","milk"]; 
var dat1=[1,3,5]; // assigning the values
var data1=["milk","veggies"]; // this data should generate 5 white squares and 3 green squares.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing in your jsfiddle -- there're several nested calls that create data and set up timers... In principle, you would push the same data item however often you want it to the array you pass to D3's `.data()`.

Comment: I tried .data(data1), but it generated only 1 square. So, I tried getting the data one by one and then used it to generate the squares every 40ms. I've removed the unwanted lines and here is my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/25QHv/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to translate your data into the following format?

```
["fruits", "fruits", "veggies", "veggies", "veggies", "milk", "milk", "milk", "milk", "milk"]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P89Fk/

Comment: Thank you so much... Just what I wanted.